# HTML - multiple <audio> tags

Tags: php, html, html5-audio

I am writing a website for a school project in PHP+HTML+CSS.
It is a website about a School-Orchestra.
I tried to use multiple audio-tags.
But it only displays the first  and .
Here is my Code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
        <!-- HTML5 Extra Angaben für Umlaute werden unnötig -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <!-- HTML 4.x Extra Angaben für Umlaute werden unnötig -->
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Con Fuoco</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php
   include("nav.html");
  ?>
        <div class="text">
        <h1>Die 9. Sinfonie von <a href="ad.php"></a>Antonín Dvořák</h1>
        <h2>Allgemeines</h2>
        <p>Die 9. Sinfonie von Antonin Dvorak entstand w&auml;hrend Dvorak's dreij&auml;hrigem Amerika-Aufenthaltes und wurde auch von diesem inspiriert.</p>
        <p></p>
        <h2>Original-Besetzung</h2>
        <p>2 Flöten (2. auch Piccoloflöte), 2 Oboen (2. auch Englischhorn), 2 Klarinetten, 2 Fagotte, 4 Hörner, 2 Trompeten, 3 Posaunen, Tuba, Pauke, Triangel, Becken, Streicher</p>
        <h2>H&ouml;rprobe? Ja!</h2>
        <!-- Problem zum lösen: Zeigt nur erstes <h3> und <audio> and-->
        <h3>1. Satz: Adagio - Allegro molto</h3>
        <audio src="./files/9-ad-1.ogg" controls /a>
        <h3>2. Satz: Largo</h3>
        <audio src="./files/9-ad-2.ogg" controls /a>
        <h3>3. Satz: Scherzo, Molto vivace</h3>
        <audio src="./files/9-ad-3.ogg" controls /a>
        <h3>4. Satz: Allegro con fuoco</h3>
        <audio src="./files/9-ad-4.ogg" controls /a>
        <!---->
        </div>
  <?php
   include("besucher.php");
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try checking the page generated source code. Maybe closing with `</audio>` and removing `/a` from the code helps.

Comment: Thanks! Works now. Well I guess that was too easy. ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [FirstOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4577762/firstone)!

Removing the /a> at the and and closing the tag normally works.

```html
        <!---->
        <h3>1. Satz: Adagio - Allegro molto</h3>
        <audio src="./files/9-ad-1.ogg" controls></audio>
        <h3>2. Satz: Largo</h3>
        <audio src="./files/9-ad-2.ogg" controls></audio>
        <h3>3. Satz: Scherzo, Molto vivace</h3>
        <audio src="./files/9-ad-3.ogg" controls></audio>
        <h3>4. Satz: Allegro con fuoco</h3>
        <audio src="./files/9-ad-4.ogg" controls></audio>
        <!---->
```